# rechanging uploaded image size

Tags: slider, resize

I have a slider on my website asp.net and I have assigned a specific users to upload the images for this slider. how can I control the size of the image they upload to fit my slider size. is there a way to rechange the image size during uploading without loosing quality.

I have tried to apply a restriction on the uploading size but i dont want to do that im just looking for another way more user friendly